# C# Worker: read and execute one file after another in each loop pass

Tags: c#, loops, worker-service

in a directory of mine, there are several (.sql-)files. Now I am trying to write a worker service, which grabs one file, executes it and deletes it afterwards. Then he shall go forward to the next one and so on, until no file is there anymore.

I already wrote some code:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\MyFolder\");
        if (filePaths.Length != 0)
        {
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                ExecuteSQLFile(filePath);
            }
        }                

        await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

As you hopefully can see, with the command `Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\MyFolder\")` he always reads the complete file system in each loop pass of the `while`-loop.

What i try to achieve now, is that in each loop pass, he only reads ONE file and executes it, in the next loop pass the next one and so on.

Is that possible? Can someone please assist and show me how to do this? Or can you at least give me a small hint? How to get rid of the `foreach`-loop in the code above?

Comment: Maybe a [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-6.0) is the right choice for you.

Comment: Do you pretend to monitor the file system for new files and read them once they are available? Maybe you should extend a bit more your explanation.

Comment: Hello @all and thank you really much for your help efforts... the scenario is as follows: The worker loops over a directory, so he looks each 1 sec into that folder, and if there is a new file: execute + delete it, if there are multible: execute and delete the first one, next loop pass execute + delete the next one and so on (so always the top one)

Comment: That changes the premise massively and should really have been included in your original question text... anyways, I'll get to re-re-writing my answer

Answer (score 3):

OP (once again) changed the premise of the question. Now we only have to deal with new files, the ones executed are deleted. That makes this quite a bit easier

```cs
while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    var file = Directory
        .EnumerateFiles(@"E:\MyFolder\")
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (file != null)
    {
        ExecuteSQLFile(file);
        // Remove the next line if 'ExecuteSQLFile' handles file deletion
        File.Delete(file);
    }

    await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
}
```

Note that deleting a file *safely* is somewhat more work than just `File.Delete`, there are tons of ways deleting a file could fail

---

Thanks [Gabriel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18307736/gabriel) for pointing out that `Directory.EnumerateFiles` exists, allowing me to read just the files I'm interested in, and not read out the entire content of the directory every time

Comment: What happens, when a file is deleted/added to the directory?

Comment: I misunderstood OP, they want to have this service always running and once every second execute one SQL file. I'll update the answer

Comment: Hello @MindSwipe and thank you really much for your answer, please excuse and correct me if im wrong, but doesn't he now again read the complete file system within one loop?^^

Comment: Is it within one loop possible not to read all files in that given folder, but only the top one? xD

Comment: @Sam, yup, that's quite easy. Using LINQ `files.First()` or just directly indexing `files[0]`, both of these need a `if (files.Length > 0)` check first though

Comment: Wow, I think that was what I was searching for thank you really really much again :) Sorry for the problems expressing myself precisely

Comment: @Sam no problem, happens to the best of us. BTW I just edited it to fix a problem that could lead to the worker just spinning forever and not actually waiting a second between attempts (if the directory were empty)

Comment: If only the first file is relevant, you could use `Direcotry.EnumerateFiles(@"E:\MyFolder\").FirstOrDefault()` (see [Diectory.EnumerateFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=net-6.0)) instead. So you don't have to return all files in the directory before continue execution. If there are many files in the folder, this could be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel, I was looking for something like that but forgot that `Directory.EnumerateFiles` exists